# How can I compute the effects in the same way as R's lm.fit()?

Tags: r, lm

Non-statistician here, porting some R code to Python.

I need R's `lm.fit` in Python.

Porting R code has been straightforward, but since `lm.fit` calls the C function `C_Cdqrls` I hit a bump.

I have started copying `lm.fit` by using `numpy.linalg.lstsq`:

```
lstsq_sol, residuals, rank, singulars = lstsq(x, y, 1e-07)
```

This gives me the least-squares solution, sums of residuals, rank and singulars.

However, I want to compute the `fit$effects` - how do I do that?

The code is here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/lm.R#L114

(And what are the `z$pivots` and `z$pivoted` refered to in the `lm.fit` code - do I need to worry about those?

Ps. there is a question that seems very similar, but the question and answer do not seem to include how to compute the effects (at least I can't figure out how: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130704/how-the-effectsqy-in-lm-fit-calculated.)

Comment: Perhaps the Q refered to in the linked to question is from here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html

Comment: Did you find a way to do it ? Because i'm looking for doing the same thing in scala but i don't understand how they compute residuals.

Comment: Sorry, no, but if you find a way, please tell me :)

Comment: The function is in Fortran: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/master/src/appl/dqrls.f

Comment: I think the `lm.R` line number has fallen out of date since you referenced `trunk`... could you please update the link to the correct current line and then make the link permanent by adding a commit ref?